# Was spying on the Chancellor against the Jedi code?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Anakin reacts furiously when the Council asks him to spy on the Chancellor:

> **ANAKIN:** You're asking me to do something ***against the Jedi Code***. Against the Republic. Against a mentor and a friend. That's what's out of place here. Why are you asking this of me?

Does the Jedi Code forbid spying on an authority? How was spying on Palpatine a violation of the Jedi Code?

Comment: I think it's more that they're asking him to lie and betray the chancellor's confidence, which goes against everything the Jedi supposedly believe in.

Comment: A musical?...that's a good idea.  I'm on it.

Answer (score 6):

The Jedi Code isn't like you might be thinking it is.  It's not a set of laws written in stone (although there is a mantra that they stick too).  It is a Code that governs their life, forbids having more than one Padawan and also having romantic relationships.  The Code teaches the Jedi to have compassion for all lives, and especially to not give in to anger.  The mantra they use is:

> There is no emotion, there is peace.
>   There is no ignorance, there is knowledge.
>   There is no passion, there is serenity.
>   There is no chaos, there is harmony.
>   There is no death, there is the Force

Anakin felt that spying on Palpatine was against what he thought of as the Jedi Code.  Maybe he thought it created chaos where there should have been harmony.  His interpretation of the Jedi Code was against spying on other people, especially if they happen to be one of your best friends.  Even if they're actually a Sith lord in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

I think Anakin believed spying to be a violation of the code because it is basically morally wrong.  By becoming a spy, it gave him an ulterior motive in his friendship with Palpatine, thus becoming a lie, which isn't exactly covered in the code, but neither is being a lousy person, which is what being a liar makes you.